# Only update statement runs not the Select statement SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In my SQL query here. When I separate both the update (from line 1 to where 1=1) and the Select (Select *, to the end), they both run on my table. But when I put these 2 together like my query below only my update statement is running. How should I reformat my sql query so that both the update and select run.

```js
update `np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.sla_table`
set expected_start_date = timestamp(CONCAT( EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP(start_date)),' '
,EXTRACT(TIME FROM TIMESTAMP(expected_start_date)) )), 
expected_end_date = timestamp(CONCAT( EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP(end_date)),' '
,EXTRACT(TIME FROM TIMESTAMP(expected_end_date)) ))
where 1=1;

SELECT *,  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(start_date, expected_start_date, MINUTE) AS Difference_Start_Time, 

TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_date, expected_end_date, MINUTE)  AS Difference_End_Time,

CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(start_date, expected_start_date, MINUTE) <= 0 THEN TRUE WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(start_date, expected_start_date, MINUTE) > 0 THEN FALSE END AS Started_On_Time,

CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_date, expected_end_date, MINUTE) <= 0 THEN TRUE WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_date, expected_end_date, MINUTE) > 0 THEN FALSE END AS end_date_tracker,

CASE WHEN end_date is null then 'FAILED' ELSE 'COMPLETED' END AS status_tracker 
FROM `np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.sla_table`;
```

Comment: I have not used bigquery in a while, but it used to not support this. Very annoying. You might check out their docs on scripting or "executing multiple SQL statements" - I am not sure if they support it now, but definitely there was a time where they didnt, and I hate it.

Comment: I looked it up "BigQuery supports multi-statement transactions inside a single query, or across multiple queries when using sessions. A multi-statement transaction lets you perform mutating operations, such as inserting or deleting rows on one or more tables, and either commit or roll back the changes atomically." Is my query suppose to run and its still bigqueries fault or is there another way to format the query so that both can run

Comment: Are you running in the BigQuery UI? If so, your statement will generate two jobs: one for the `update` and another for the `select`, as expected.